# Maximize window when dragged to top in Mint/Cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, window-manager, cinnamon

In Windows 7, when I drag a window to the top of the screen, it maximizes. In Mint, however, it takes only the upper half of the screen. Can I make it maximize instead, line in Windows?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open Cinnamon Settings, choose "Window Tiling and Edge Flip" and uncheck the "Maximize, instead of tile, when dragging a window to the top edge" checkbox:

[image]

If you see something like the image below instead, you need to switch to advanced mode:

[image]